# JPA : Update and return new value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

With JPA, I'm trying to update a value in the table and also return the new value.

The schema :

```
CREATE TABLE CountTable (
    id varchar(255) primary key,

    productName varchar(255),
    count long
);
```

My code :

```
 @Modifying
  @Transactional
  @Query(value = "update CountTable ct set ct.count = ct.count + 1 where ct.productName = ?1; " +
          "select ct.count from CountTable ct where ct.productName=?1", nativeQuery = true)
  public Integer addCount(String productName);
```

And I get this error :

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/v1/db] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: JPA-style positional param was not an integral ordinal] with root cause
```

I have to run both the queries together since there would be multiple pods running and the data needs to be consistent.

How to fix this issue, or is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to bundle that into a procedure.

Comment: These are separate queries that need to be executed as separate statements - you need an updateCount and getCount methods you run in the same transactional method. Or you create a stored procedure in the database to do this

Comment: @Chris will creating stored procedure guarentee atomicity?

Comment: If the procedure is in a transaction, sure. You absolutely can do the same thing server side though with two separate methods, one for update, one for get that participate in the same transaction. What you are doing is pretty much the same as what JPA providers do for table sequencing solutions, and will use a non-JTA datasource so that the update+select can be done outside of the current transaction so as to not block throughput as much.

Answer (score 0):

These are 2 logical operations: Update and Read (updated value).
So first try to update value if entity exists, then fetch the updated data.

```
@Query ("just 1 native query", native = true)
```

Comment: So the issue for me with this approach is that there will be multiple servers accessing the mySql. So running two operations separately might result in data inconsistancy

Comment: If you are using service-repository architecture -> make service transactional instead of repository (simple solution), or somebody in the comments mentioned DB procedure - valid and fast approach (you will have to lock the row for isolation)